# Get current culture using just formula for localization purpose

Tags: excel, localization, excel-formula, globalization

Is there a way how to determine current system culture using a formula in Excel **wihout using any VBA code**?

I imagine something simple like this:

```
IF(CULTURE="sk-SK","Prehľad","Overview")
```

or also something like this would do for me:

```
IF(CURRENCYSIGN="€","Prehľad","Overview")
```

I am looking for a simple way to globalize XLSX file without any additional resources or files needed.

Comment: I have an idea but can't test it as I need non-English version of Excel for this. Do you have Czech Excel 2013?

Comment: Try writing `=DNES()` in `A1` and `=FORMULATEXT(A1)` in `A2`. What do you get?

Comment: Yes, great, I get `=DNES()`.

Comment: Brilliant. I will update my answer. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to get system language settings without VBA. There is simply no built-in function for this. But if you consider UDF, there's a solution:

```
Public Function GetLang()
    GetLang = Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)
End Function
```

However, with your help we have found a trick. You can guess the system language by analyzing formula text (only in Excel 2013):

```
A1=TODAY()
=IF(FORMULATEXT(A1)="=TODAY()",[some logic for English system],[some logic for non-English system])
```

Or by analyzing local month name:

```
=IF(TEXT(1,"mmmm")="January",[some logic for English system],[some logic for non-English system])
```