# Excel TEXT(dd.mm.yyyy) function and different client languages

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, vba

How can I make a function with a formatted date that will work in every language? I want to make the following function:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(C8;"TT.MM.JJJJ");"/";G8)
```

The problem here is, that I use the english client but because I'm a german, excel forces me to use T for day and J for year. I think this will cause problem on a PC located in england (for example).

I think `[$-409]` won't work because I still have to use T for day and J for year. Is there a good solution for this (function wise)?

Comment: Could you change the localisation settings on your PC to match that of your client?

Comment: I could maybe, but this doesn't sounds optimal. I want to make this worksheet read able for everyone, no matter what country.

Comment: Vityata's answer is probably on the right track, write yourself a vba function that checks something like `Application.International(xlApplicationInternational.xlCountryCode) ` (from [here](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/macros/region-language.htm)) to determine which fromatting string to return

Comment: @Dan - indeed, the `xlCountryCode` is a better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass the value of a formula in `""` then it cannot be changed based on the localisation settings.

A good way to do it is to use a custom function with VBA, returning `"TT.MM.JJJJ"` if you are in Germany and `"DD.MM.YYYY"` if you are in England.

```
Public Function CorrectString() As String

    Select Case Application.International(XlApplicationInternational.xlCountryCode)
        Case 1
            CorrectString = "DD.MM.YYYY"
        Case 49
            CorrectString = "TT.MM.JJJJ"
        Case Else
            CorrectString = "ERROR"
    End Select

End Function
```

Would allow you to call the function like this:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(C8;CorrectString());"/";G8)
```

And depending on the excel language, it would give either the German or the English versions.

To simplify the formula, try calling only:

```
 =TEXT(21322;CorrectString())
```

This should return `17.05.1958`.

Source for the regional languages, mentioned by @Dan at the comments:
https://bettersolutions.com/vba/macros/region-language.htm

Or run this to see the corresponding number of your current Excel:

```
MsgBox xlApplicationInternational.xlCountryCode
```

Comment: Is there such a built-in function?

Comment: @Dan - actually I meant a custom function, not a built-in one.

Comment: Thank you! It's crazy for me that there isn't any other way than writing down a VBA code.

Comment: @Bluesector - probably there should be another way. This sounds like a standard problem. But I cannot research & replicate, I have Excel only in 1 language.

Comment: Somehow `=CONCATENATE(TEXT(C8;CorrectString);"/";G8)` gives me a `#NAME?` Error. I pasted the VBA code into the "ThisWorkbook" area.

Comment: @Bluesector - put the VBA in a module.https://www.microsofttraining.net/article-1711-what-are-modules-in-excel-vba-coding.html

Comment: `"Ambiguous name detected: CorrectString"`

Comment: @Bluesector - you should delete the one from the `ThisWorkbook` area.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162732/discussion-between-bluesector-and-vityata).

Answer (score 4):

Just dropping in another imho elegant (VBA free) alternative taken from: [Stackoverflow answer by @Taosique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715106/get-current-culture-using-just-formula-for-localization-purpose)

```
=IF(TEXT(1,"mmmm")="January",[some logic for English system],[some logic for non-English system])
```

Comment: This is a super elegant solution! Used it to make a calculated TEXT()-formula work between English + German Excel versions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and solved it with similar VBA Function. My function accepts input in international format, and outputs the local version for user.

Please see code below:

```
Function DateFormater(sFI As String)

Dim aFI() As String
aFI = split(StrConv(sFI, vbUnicode), Chr$(0))
ReDim Preserve aFI(UBound(aFI) - 1)

For i = 0 To UBound(aFI)
    Select Case (aFI(i))
    Case "m", "M"
        DateFormater = DateFormater & Application.International(xlMonthCode)
    Case "y", "Y"
        DateFormater = DateFormater & Application.International(xlYearCode)
    Case "d", "D"
        DateFormater = DateFormater & Application.International(xlDayCode)
    Case Else
        DateFormater = DateFormater & aFI(i)
    End Select
Next i

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution is to use generic Excel functions.

=CONCATENATE(TEXT(DAY(C8;"00");".";TEXT(MONTH(C8);"00");".";YEAR(C8);"/";G8)